# is there a change that if maximum session capacity is over, the site will get logged out?

Tags: php, session, zend-framework, socialengine

is there a change that if maximum session capacity is over, the site will get logged out?

On a site we have lots of session data, and we are saving the images that we upload to the site as a session variable and shows the preview After clicking the save button the image will get saved to the server and entered the details in to the database.

But if we upload more that 3 images the user is getting logged out.
How ever this is working perfectly on local machine. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is existing in socialengine. One solution is **increase the server memory limit** but it has also a limit.

second and perfect solution for large storage session problem is use **file instead of session.**. Write data to the file. Use file read and write procedure on the place of session read and save.

Answer (score 0):

increase your session timeout value.

```php
$session = new Zend_Session_Namespace( 'Zend_Auth' );
$session->setExpirationSeconds(60*60);
```